# sharing or referencing an instance of one class in another classes object

Tags: c++, oop, object

I am writing a program that contains several classes and I am trying to access class `A` instance from class `B`. I am using `setA()` and `getA()` for `A`'a data member and I am using the same for class `B`. In class `B` I also have a function that gets the member from `A` via the `getA()` function call. I then want to compare if `A`'s member is the same as `B`'s member.

```
class A {
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        void setA(int a);
        int getA();
}

class B {
    private:
        int b;
    public:
        void setB(int b);
        int getB();

        bool compareA_B(){
            A a.getA(); //   <- this is a new object A
            B b.getB();
            if(a == b)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
}
```

When I call `setA()` in my main function by `A a_in_main.setA(2)` this `A` is a different instance than the one above with the arrow.

My question is how do I access the correct instance of `A` in the `B` function `compare()`?

I kind of think I need to use pointers but I am not sure. I have been looking all over the internet and I can't find anything concrete.

I edited this post and I hope this is more clear.

Comment: You'll need a pointer or reference. I'd start with `shared_ptr`s for now since they'll avoid you having to deal with object lifetime issues.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring `int a` you are declaring that the class' instance will hold an int, not a reference to one.

When you're setting you also do the same in the function by passing the argument by value (which most likely copies in real world scenarios), so even if it was a pointer internally you could end up with your "reference" referring to a newly made copy.

Your member, and the signature of the functions handling it, need to be pointers or references of some flavor to an int, which will store the memory address it's located at, and when compared will compare memory locations and not the value stored in it.

The syntax for a pointer to a value of some type is `type* var`.

`int* var`, `int *var`, `int * var` are all equivalent, you will find it expressed all ways depending on the author.

You might also, depending on what the intended use of that member is, want to ensure it can't alter the data it points to `const int* var`.

It sounds like you're very early on in learning C++, some beginner books or YouTube videos might help. Wrapping referenced values in classes before you know how to make a pointer might be a sign of trying to run before being able to walk.

Comment: just to clarify are you suggesting that I declare `int a` as a pointer so `int * a` and then edit `compareA_B()` to `compareA_B(int* )` and should I change my `int getA()` to `int * getA()` and then I can pass that to the edited `compareA_B` function? I figured I need to use pointers but I wasn't certain the proper way of doing it. Thanks for the response I will try this right away.

Comment: If you want to compare whether both refer to the same address in memory (e.g. changing one affects the other), then yes, you need to switch that member (and the signatures of functions managing it) to a pointer (`int* a` as suggested). `int a` would get you (and compare) the value stored there, and not where it's stored.